withInMemoryScrolling({ scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' }) not work in standalone api
When switching to another router, the page appears slightly scrolled. To fix this, I use the withInMemoryScrolling function with the { scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' } parameter. According to the documentation, this should set the scroll position to x = 0, y = 0 on all navigation, but it doesn't work.
Here is my code below
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(appRoutes,
      withInMemoryScrolling({ scrollPositionRestoration: 'top' })),
  ],
});

Angular version - 17.1.0

Does this happen on all browsers?

I checked it in Chrome and Firefox, and it happens there and there

Try this:


provideRouter(
   appRoutes,
   withInMemoryScrolling({ scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' }),
)



Hope it works for you

The problem was in the overflow-x:hidden property added earlier to the html tag

You also can't use height: 100% or height: 100vh as then the window is technically not scrolling anymore. Took me all day to figure that one out.
